# 3 different tables (1 table associated). When I make a call. the incoming value is replicated

Tags: mysql, sql

first table

```
a.id | a.name 
  1  |   apple
  2  |   peace
  3  |   grape
```

second table

```
b.id | b.name
 1   |  yellow
 2   |  red
 3   |  green
```

thidr relationship table

```
a.id | b.id
 1   |   2
 1   |   1
 3   |   3
 3   |   1
 2   |   1
```

I want to see :

```
...LIKE '%pe%' and tag 'green';
peace green
grape green
```

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
    INNER JOIN c ON a.a_id = c.a_id
    INNER JOIN b ON c.b_id = b.b_id
WHERE a.a_name LIKE '%pe%'
```

Comment: You've almost got the WHERE clause. Now also have a try with the rest of the query.

Comment: I don't see the column `tag` in your tables? Do you mean `b.name`?

Comment: You are almost there. Just add the joins.

Comment: @waka I tired SELECT * FROM a
INNER JOIN c ON a.a_id = c.a_id
INNER JOIN b ON c.b_id = b.b_id
WHERE a.a_name LIKE '%pe%'; I see value duplicate 1-grape green 2-grape  yellow 3- peace  yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is better ways to form that query but this seems to get you what you need.

```
select f.name as fruit, c.name as color from
fruit_color as fc 
  join fruit as f on f.id = fc.fruit_id
  join color as c on c.id = fc.color_id
where f.name like '%pe%' and c.name like '%green%'
```

Output:

```
fruit | color
---------------
grape | green
peace | green
```

---

[**sqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23fbde/1/0)

Comment: but I do not want duplicate

Comment: Just include the color in your where clause if you also want to include that.